# Using JwtSecurityToken for Authorization header in http

Tags: c#, jwt, http-headers, authorization

I have an API I need to call with a user token. I receive the token as a [JwtSecurityToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken?view=azure-dotnet) and need to add it to my http headers. My issue is that I am not sure how to use that token with the HTTP Headers.

When I tried

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```

I got a FormatException on the token.

I expect I should be using one of the properties of `token`, but I do not know which one, or what is the proper way to send.

How can I use the JwtSecurityToken I have un the authorization headers for HTTP?

Comment: Adding the bearer token in your header is correct.  You need to provide more details on the token

Comment: Added a link about the token class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, the field `RawData` is what is desired. So the correct way to use the JwtSecurityToken in the header is as follows:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.RawData}");
```